# Adding padding to scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I am executing container with padding at the end. It is going well except last part of it, the scrollbar doesn't take padding like container does padding.

```css
.wrapper{
       margin-top: 30vh;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .slider{
      white-space: nowrap;
        display: inline-flex;
        margin-right: 120px;
    }
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
        <section class="slider">
         Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi cumque perferendis dolorem voluptatum, nesciunt minima est soluta facere illo mollitia iste eveniet eos, magni ad sit, veritatis ullam optio molestiae libero dolore. Modi quo ad minima vero architecto hic in!  
        </section>
    </section>
```

[Check on Codepen](https://codepen.io/tarekhassan/pen/YzZbZQq)

Comment: This is because you specified `margin-right` instead of `padding-right`

Comment: Your rejection of the edit and subsequent edit of your own removed the link to the codepen and the image has vanished. Also, "scrollbar" is spelled incorrectly in the title of your post.

Comment: I didn't understand the edit, the edit looked something like JavaSript or React with "ScrollBar" and "Babel true" or something like that, I wanted to keep it simple.
Also, I removed the image because it got confusing with the image and link. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.wrapper {
     margin-top: 30vh;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     width: 100%;
}
 .slider {
     white-space: nowrap;
     display: inline-flex;
     margin-right: 120px;
}
 .slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
     padding-right: 18px; // Add your own padding here.
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <section class="slider">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi cumque perferendis dolorem voluptatum, nesciunt minima est soluta facere illo mollitia iste eveniet eos, magni ad sit, veritatis ullam optio molestiae libero dolore. Modi quo ad minima vero
    architecto hic in!
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: No padding right is not working, tried it.

Comment: @tarekhassan Did you try the above code snippet? I see it solves the whitespace.

Comment: The scrollbar is the problem. The scrollbar is till the end not till the end of the slider.

Comment: @tarekhassan Which Slider? I don't see any sliders. I see a text with scrollBar.

Comment: I updated the question. I added Codepen to clarify more but it got confusing.
The idea is that container has padding at the end, I want the scrollbar to have padding too.